# How to create email alerts based on inside code functionality of Azure Function App - Timer Trigger?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, timer-trigger

**Scenario**: Enabling Health Check Monitoring of APIM APIs and Email Alerts if the API is not healthy.

**Using**: Azure Functions - C# - Consumption Based Model

```cs
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())

            {

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
                try
                {
                    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                    var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
                    if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        log.LogInformation($"URL is healthy. Status code: {statusCode}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        log.LogError($"URL is not healthy. Status code: {statusCode}");
                        // Trigger an alert or take any other action here using Azure Monitor or other monitoring solutions.
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.LogError($"Error occurred while checking the URL: {ex.Message}");
                   // Handle any exceptions that might occur during the request.
                }
            }
```

**Result**:

`URL is healthy. Status code: OK` - This is the log message written inside the Azure Function Code.

I Know how to create alerts if azure function fails to run but I'm not getting idea how to create alerts (Eg: email alerts) when the above function gives the result as `URL is not healthy. Status code: {statusCode}`.

Comment: 1. Do not use String interpolation in Log messages (which are actually message _templates_). 2. I am pretty sure you can have monitoring on a health-endpoint directly ... I'll try to find some more info. I guess you aware of this: [Monitor App Service instances using Health check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check?tabs=dotnet) ?

Comment: We have Resource Health Feature in APIM Service but that will not give the individual API Level. That will give the APIM Service Level Alert like https://i.stack.imgur.com/znAgy.png + https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7UlF.png

Comment: So you went to send an email, correct?

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods, I’m curious, why shouldn’t one use string interpolation in log messages? I’ve never seen that suggested.

Comment: Yes @Skin, you are correct

Comment: @Skin Really? Well, avoiding string interpolation allows for structured logging. You can of course interpolate the _template_.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods, yeah, really. Why is it such a problem for someone to want to log a straight string with parameters passed in? Not all logging needs to be structured. Your comment makes it sound like you should never do it. Logs are functional for those who are consuming them, horses for courses.

Comment: @HariKrishna, have you looked at using something like SendGrid or even LogicApps? Makes life easy.

Comment: Looking at SendGrid @Skin

Comment: @Skin It's all about habits.